# REST PUT Response format

Tags: java, android, http, rest

I have an android application with a MySQL database. Rows entered on the android tablet need to be synchronised on a server, also with MySql. Once written onto the server the server Unique Integer needs to be returned to the tablet to update the local database. That way it will x-ref the client to the server. It currently works by performing a PUT for each row and using the location for the server ID in the response. However it takes ages if there are a significant amount of updates, inserts as each one row opens a new HttpConnection. I would like to be able to group the updates in one XML String and get an XML file returned with the xreference of the serverID for each Client ID. However I cannot find a way of sending XML in the response, only a URI. My connection code is

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, Const.HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, Const.HTTP_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,new UsernamePasswordCredentials("xxxxx","xxxxx"));  // TODO Change to logged user name
HttpPut put = new HttpPut(uri);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xml);
entity.setContentType("application/xml");
put.setEntity(entity);
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(put.getParams(), false);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
switch (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()){
case 200:
case 201:
    location = response.getLastHeader("Location").getValue();
    key = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    break;
case 401:
    throw new RuntimeException("Authorisation Failed");
default:
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to Create Data Record on Server");
            }
```

And on the Server

```
if (flight.getClientFlightId()!=0){
if (insertFlight(userId)){
    xref += "<clientId>"+flight.getClientFlightId()+"</clientId><serverId>"+flight.getServerFlightId()+"</serverId>";
    }
}
xref +="</xref>";
response = Response.created(URI.create(xref)).build();
```

Anyone able to help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> putParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
putParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myXML", "<xml> _PUT_YOUR_XML_HERE_ </xml>"));
UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(putParams);
put.setEntity(formEntity);
```

Comment: not what I meant. Getting the xml in a PUT works fine. I just want an XML back as well.